# Installing scribd_fu with Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scribd

Rails noob here. I want users of my app to be able to upload page (pdf, .doc) that is then uploaded to Scribd and viewable in the browser. From my research, it looks like the best way to accomplish this in Rails is the scribd_fu gem: https://github.com/shwoodard/scribd_fu

I have been trying unsuccessfully to install the gem. The README instructions are a bit outdated but it says to install with:

```
    sudo gem install scribd_fu --source 'http://gemcutter.com'
    config.gem 'scribd_fu', :source => 'http://gemcutter.com'
    ./script/generate scribd_fu
```

Since I understand the above is mostly deprecated in Rails 3.x, I instead added the following to my gem file and ran 'bundle install'

```
    gem 'rscribd'
    gem 'scribd_fu'
```

That seems to install the gems but I can't actually run the scribd_fu generator. I've tried:

```
    rails generate scribd_fu
    bundle exec rails generate scribd_fu
```

When I run the above I get error message: "Could not find generator scribd_fu". When I run rails g --help, scribd_fu is not listed as any of the available generators. Any help would be appreciated as this gem seems to do exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: what's the error that you get when executing the generation commands? did you try rails generate --help ?

Comment: I updated the question to include the error message. Scribd_fu is not showing up on the generator list at all when I do rails g --help

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scribd_fu gem [source code](https://github.com/shwoodard/scribd_fu/blob/master/generators/scribd_fu/templates/scribd_fu.yml), all the scribd_fu gem generator creates a YAML file called scribd_fu.yml in your config directory (ie. config/scribd_fu.yml)

The contents of the scribd_fu.yml file are as follows:

```
#Scribd Account Info

key: 
secret: 
user: 
password: 
access:
```

Until someone answers with a better way, just create the file by hand and you should be able to move on.